# Numpy: compare each element of array with all other elements (± constant)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

I have a 1D Numpy array `A` of length `N`. For each element `x` in the array, I want to know what proportion of all elements in the array are within the range [`x-eps`; `x+eps`], where `eps` is a constant. `N` is in the order of 15,000.

At present I do it as follows (minimal example):

```py
import numpy as np

N = 15000
eps = 0.01
A = np.random.rand(N, 1)
prop = np.array([np.mean((A >= x - eps) & (A <= x + eps)) for x in A])
```

.. which takes around 1 sec on my computer.

My question: is there a more efficient way of doing this?

**Edit:** I think @jdehesa suggestion in the comments would work as follows:

```py
prop = np.isclose(A, A.T, atol=eps, rtol=0).mean(axis=1)
```

It's a nice concise solution, but without a speed advantage (on my computer).

Comment: [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) / [`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. See my edit for an attempt to implement it by means of `np.isclose`.

Comment: another option is to sort the array (O(n log n)) and then run a sliding window (O(n)), counting elements within the window. It will be O(n log n) in total, comparing to O(n^2) solution, but cannot be effectively vectorized and thus probably will be slower on a 15k array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a good setup to leverage [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
sidx = A.argsort()
ridx = np.searchsorted(A, A+eps, 'right', sorter=sidx)
lidx = np.searchsorted(A, A-eps, 'left', sorter=sidx)
out = ridx - lidx
```

Timings -

```
In [71]: N = 15000
    ...: eps = 0.01
    ...: A = np.random.rand(N)

In [72]: %timeit np.array([np.sum((A >= x - eps) & (A <= x + eps)) for x in A])
560 ms ± 5.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: sidx = A.argsort()
    ...: ridx = np.searchsorted(A, A+eps, 'right', sorter=sidx)
    ...: lidx = np.searchsorted(A, A-eps, 'left', sorter=sidx)
    ...: out = ridx - lidx
5.35 ms ± 47.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Further improvement with pre-sorting :**

```
In [81]: %%timeit
    ...: sidx = A.argsort()
    ...: b = A[sidx]
    ...: ridx = np.searchsorted(b, A+eps, 'right')
    ...: lidx = np.searchsorted(b, A-eps, 'left')
    ...: out = ridx - lidx
3.93 ms ± 19.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As stated in the comments, for the `mean` equivalent version, simply divide final array output by `N`.

Comment: This is fantastic, the speed-up is incredible. Thanks!

Comment: For future Googelers: obviously one has to divide `out` by `N`, which is not really relevant in terms of speed though.